# How to select all search results in MS Outlook?

Tags: catalina, ms-office

While trying to archive all emails meeting a search criteria in Microsoft Outlook 16.42 I select all and archive them. More un-archived emails meeting the original criteria then appear. How can I archive the lot of them in one fell swoop?

Comment: Wouldn't ⌘+A select all?

Comment: That's Outlook's shortcut for it, and while it looks like it's selecting everything, archiving them all leaves some behind. I'm assuming there's some maximum result count it's not selecting beyond.